# Firebase rules failed: permission_denied

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In my app I have vc1 that pushes on vc2. Inside vc2 I pull some data from Firebase.

The problem is when I set my rules to the below values, when vc2 gets pushed on I keep getting `failed: permission_denied`

```
{
  "rules": {
      "sneakers": {
      ".read": "auth != null || auth.uid === null",
      ".write": "auth.uid != null"
    },
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I go back to vc1, change the values to the below, then I get no problems and I get access

```
{
  "rules": {
     ".read": "auth.uid != null",
     ".write": "auth.uid != null"
  }
}
```

But here's the thing, once I set them back to the first values, go back to vc1 then push on vc2 I can then still get access to the database. If I delete the app and relaunch it the process repeats itself.

I want to use the first values because I want to keep the data at the user's node safe.

**Why won't do I keep getting `permission_denied` with my first values, make a change to the rules, then after I change them  back I no longer get `permission denied`? Where am I going wrong in my rules**

vc2:

```
let root = Database.database().reference()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        root?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
              (snapshot) in

               // sneakers node might not exist                   
               if snapshot.hasChild("sneakers/nike)"){
                   ....
               }
        )}
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        root?.removeAllObservers()
}
```

The database layout:

```
root
  |
  @-sneakers // this node might not exist
  |    |
  |   nike
  |
  @-users
  |    |
  |   uid
  |
  @-jackets...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to read from the root of your database (`root?.observeSingleEvent(...`), but you only grant access to individual users and sneakers nodes. Since you're trying to read more than you have access to, Firebase rejects your observer.

It's hard to say why sometimes you don't get this error, but most likely it's a caching issue. Either your new rules haven't been applied yet (which should be rare), or you're reading from the cache of your iOS device (where the data was stored when you still *did* have access).

Either way, you should make sure you only read data you have access to. So:

```
root?.child("sneakers/nike")?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
      (snapshot) in

       // sneakers node might not exist                   
       if snapshot.exists() {
           ....
       }
)}
```